# calling Angular js file with partial doesn't work for first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http

I am trying to load following js with partial, using $http . my problem is when i run code firest time get controller undefined type error,
where as on second click it works fine.

**JAVASCRIPT::**

```
$scope.loadPage = function(testurl) {
            $scope.testpage = testurl;
            var element = angular.element($("#data_template"));
            $http.get(testurl).success(function(data) {
                element.html(data);
                $compile(element.contents())($rootScope);
                $('.div1').slideUp('slow');
                $('#data_template').slideDown('slow');
            });
        };
```

**HTML::**

```
<div class="movie-listing movie-listing-step"
 ng-controller="ProductAddController">

 <!-- all DOm PArt -->

 </div>
```

mt js comes from s3 bucket, so may be js taking long time to come and $compile starts before js load . how to solve this problem ??

Comment: put ng-controller="ProductAddController" inside body..

Comment: @Ved i dont have body tag here as i am adding above partial in body

Comment: I am posting answer. Not sure It will solve your issue or not. Try it..

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used `$viewContentLoaded`

```
app.controller('ProductAddController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loadPage = function(testurl) {
        $scope.testpage = testurl;
        var element = angular.element($("#data_template"));
        $http.get(testurl).success(function (data) {
            element.html(data);
            $compile(element.contents())($rootScope);
            $('.div1').slideUp('slow');
            $('#data_template').slideDown('slow');
        });
    }
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.loadPage(testurl);
            },0);
    });
```

Comment: where to add $viewContentLoaded>??

Comment: I am not using ng-view , i am working with ng-include .$viewContentLoaded
Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.  this is from angularjs documents.

Comment: How would I know You are not using ng-view.?

Comment: my mistake m nt using ng-include or ng-view . as u can see in above code  I am fetching and appending data dynamically. when  $compile is done it is giving error.